# Unlike Rows in Tables with No Relation

Tags: sql

So I have two tables that are unrelated but yet share some of the same data.  Trying to extract those rows that don't contain certain data.  In some of the entries, the EmpployerNo and Payer_ID are the same.  I'd like to find those entries where these two are not the same.  What would be the best way to go about doing this?

**Table 1**

```
EmployerNo,
EmployerName,
Address,
Phone
```

**Table 2**

```
Payer_ID,
PayerName,
Address,
Phone
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you want this query to do. Can you provide some sample input and output? A test harness with copy-pasteable SQL with table definitions and inserts of the input data would help a lot too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TABLE1 T
WHERE T.EmployerNo NOT IN (
    SELECT
        A.EmployerNo
    FROM
        TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B
        ON A.EmployerNo = B.Payer_ID)
```

Comment: This seem to have worked fine with a bit of tweeking.  Thanks Alot.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will select rows from both tables where EmploerNo != Payer_ID:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.EmployerNo != table2.Payer_ID
```

Answer (score -1):

WHERE EmpployerNo != Payer_ID

This will show the entry's in which EmpployerNo and Payer_ID are not the same.

Comment: Note: In some versions of SQL this operator ( !=) may be written as <>

Comment: Please keep in mind that the OP has two tables, so you should ideally show in your query how you connect those two tables.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I was already wondering why I was downvoted. ;)